# multiply and add integers in between

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in c++. I need to write a code that lets me add and multiply numbers in between two numbers I input. Example: I input 2 and 4 and the addition should be 9 and multiplication should be 24. This is what I have so far.

```
 // sum and multi.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.//

 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int num1;
   cout << "Enter number: " << endl;
   cin >> num1;

   int sum=0;
   int mul = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i <= num1; i++)
   {
      sum += i;
      while (i <= num1)
      {
         mul *= i;
      }
   }

   cout << "sum is: " << sum << mul << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Although it does the addition part it only does from 0 to what ever number I input and it does not do the multiplication part. NEED HELP!!!!

Comment: You initialize `mul` to 0. Zero times anything equals zero. Think of another number that might be a better starting point for multiplication accumulator. In any case, as currently written, you multiply all numbers between 0 and `num1` inclusive - the answer to that is always zero.

Comment: Look at your `for` loop initialization and conditions. They don't make sense. Also, your `while` loop makes no sense and should be causing an infinite loop here. Write out what you want to do; *then* try coding it.

Comment: Also, as @IgorTandetnik says, you have a logic error in your multiplication. And you never actually ask for two numbers; just one!

Comment: *I input 2 and 4* - but you have only one line where you read input from `cin`.

Answer (score 3):

You need a range of numbers so input ***two*** numbers

```
int num1, num2;

cin >> num1 >> num2;

int sum=0;
int mul = 1; // Initialize mul to 1, since anything multiplied by 0, results in 0

for (int i = num1; i <= num2; i++) // Start from num1 and end to num2
{
    sum += i;
    //while (i <= num1)  // Don't need another loop
    //{
        mul *= i;
    //}
}
```